# Categories or Diagrams?

Tags: category-theory

The terminology in the texts I’ve been reading (and on Wikipedia) hasn’t been very definitive. My question is this:

Is a “category” the collection of all commuting *diagrams* for a given type, say **Top** or **Field**, or is the term category used interchangeably with diagram, in the sense that each diagram is also a category?

Comment: A category is an appropriate collection of objects and morphisms. A diagram *inside* a category is a functor (from some other category) into that category.

Comment: Ahhh! Ok thank you very much

Comment: @NoahSchweber so then a functor is a mapping from each element of the entire category (as opposed to each element of a diagram)? Or is functor used for both mappings between diagrams *and* between categories proper?

Comment: Both categories and functors are defined prior to diagrams; if we use the word "diagram" in talking about them, it's only in an informal sense (separately from the later definition of "diagram" as a technical term). Can you give an example of a bit of text you find ambiguous? That might help.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Let **C** and **D** be categories. A *functor* *F* : **C** —> **D** is a function *F* which assigns to each **C**-object *X* a **D**-object... my question is if the categories C and D can be replaced by specific diagrams within categories or perhaps the same category...

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would it mean to change **C** or **D** in $F$? What alternative do you have in mind?

Comment: @NoahSchweber to have them be given diagrams of objects and morphisms from a category...

Comment: I still have no idea what that would mean. Can you propose a candidate formal definition? ("A functor from C to D is ..." or similar.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber umm maybe Let **D** and **E** be given diagrams of categories **A** and **B**. A functor *F*: **D** —> **E** is a function *F* which assigns to each **D**-object *X* an **E**-object...

Comment: Is it even on-base to say that a “diagram” when used informally to speak about a given, non-exhaustive collection of objects and morphisms from a category can be viewed as “separate” in some sense from the given category (**Set**, **Top**) that it’s from...? I don’t know how else to put it

Comment: I mean, it sounds like you're just talking about sub-categories (analogously to sub-groups, sub-spaces, etc.). So it does make sense. But we don't need to change the definition of functor, any more than we need to change the definition of group homomorphism: a subcategory (or subgroup, or whatever) is a category in its own right, we don't need to treat the additional data.

Comment: E.g. you would never see "Let $G$ and $H$ be given subgroups of groups $A$ and $B$. A group homomorphism $f: G\rightarrow H$ is ..." because it would be totally redundant (what role are $A$ and $B$ playing here exactly?). And all of this is treating "diagram" informally; keep in mind that the term [also has a technical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory)).

Comment: So what you’re pretty much saying is that I should just let “diagram” stay informal unless otherwise specified right

Comment: I don't know? I can't really tell what it is that you're trying to say in the first place. It *sounds* to me like you're asking why we don't define functors for subcategories (= your diagrams, I think), but that doesn't really make sense - it's like asking why we don't define group homomorphisms for subgroups, or continuous maps for subspaces, or etc. (answer: because subgroups *are* groups, subspaces *are* spaces, etc., so the definition we already have works fine).

Comment: @NoahSchweber ok clearly we’re trying to talk over a pretty wide technical chasm... I guess that was what I was asking, but of course if I had the technical knowledge to state it that way, I would have had no need to ask it. Thank you for trying to help though

Comment: @NoahSchweber ok I guess I can distill it. I’m just confused at the ambiguity of the uses of the term category. Goldblatt informally defines it as a sort of “universe of discourse” while I also see category defined as a specific *diagram* of objects and arrows... so if I see that a functor is defined as a mapping between categories, I am uncertain which of these to apply this definition to. This this make any sense whatsoever?

Comment: I think you're making the mistake of taking the informal descriptions seriously. There is only one **definition** of "category" - a collection of things called *objects*, a collection of things called *morphisms*, and some relations between these (composition, source/target) satisfying some properties (associativity, existence of identities). Everything else is informal exposition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ok fair enough. That’s probably it

Comment: It may help to consider some "toy examples" of categories. For example, let **A** be a category with two objects $a$ and $b$ and three morphisms - the (required) identity morphisms $id_a$ and $id_b$ and a single morphism $m:a\rightarrow b$. Can you describe all the functors from **A** to itself? (Here since **A** is so silly you'll have no choice but to work with the precise definition.)